# Hiding a DOM element vs manipulating DOM element for responsive website?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, media-queries, conventions

I was wondering which approach would you recommend that would be best for responsive website. The website will be using Zurb Foundation and jQuery for the frameworks.

There are two approach I know how to implement a responsive navigation. One is to simply create two kind of navigation, one for large screens and the other one is for smaller screens (or mobile phones.) It will use media queries to show and hide the element depending on the screen size.

The other approach I'm considering, instead of creating two kinds of navigation in DOM, just use single source DOM elements and just manipulate it as the size of the screen change. I'm planning to use an jQuery's `resize()`. As the screen resize to a smaller screen, all of those list items will be place on a single list and as the screen go larger it will spread to different list (`ul`s).

The things i'm considering, I'm thinking that if I do two kinds of DOM element, it wouldn't be practical and might make the website bloated. Meanwhile if I'll be using javascript to manipulate the DOM positions, it might not be a smooth experience (i'm still not sure about this).

I wanted to know your thoughts.

**My DOM elements will look something similar to this.**

```
<header>

  <ul id="social-links" class="social-links">
    <li>Facebook</li>
    <li>Twitter</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="profile">

    <li><span>Hello</span><span>John</span>
      <ul>
        <li>Profile</li>
        <li>Edit Settings</li>
        <li>Log Out</li>
      </ul>                
    </li>

  </ul>

  <nav>

    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Product</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

</header>


<ul class="mobile-alt-nav">

    <li class="greet"><span>Hello</span><span>John</span>
    <li>Profile</li>
    <li>Edit Settings</li>
    <li>Log Out</li>
    </li>

    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Product</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Contact</li>

    <li>Facebook</li>
    <li>Twitter</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using CSS for this.

Create your classes based on specific css media queries

[more info on media queries here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

You are completely right in your thinking. Replicating DOM elements should be avoided whenever possible.

It is worth taking a considered approach to structure your markup in such a way that will allow for easy transitions between breakpoint styles whenever possible.

However it is worth noting that in *some* instances it may be beneficial to duplicate content to avoid CSS bloat or remove the requirement on Javascript.

In your case, since you are considering using Javascript in an attempt to avoid duplication, I would suggest that you do in-fact duplicate the markup if the content size stays roughly around the same size as you have described. It will be far less performant to manipulate the DOM nodes with Javascript than to simply hide/show blocks with CSS.

Adding Javascript to manipulate the DOM in this way creates an unnecessary complexity. Your code will be more readable and reliable in the browser if you opt to not use Javascript here and duplicate content.

**SEO Impact**

Search engines would only penalise content appearing more than once on the same page if it appears to be spammy or an attempt at keyword stuffing. However, simply duplicating DOM elements in the manner that you are suggesting would not have an impact.

I hope this helps.